# How to assign a Javascript variable to PHP variable in symfony2?

Tags: javascript, symfony, php-5.3

I am new to web development and I am using symfony2 for this project I am working on.

Have a template file called **view.html.php** and Inside this I have a JavaScript portion, inside which I want to assign JavaScript variable to PHP variable..I tried to do the following way but it did not work. Could some one please help me out with this.

```
<script>
  ....
  var temp=json;

   //error below
  <?php $jsonobj= = temp ?> 
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: You can't. You can assign a PHP variable to JavaScript, but you can't do the opposite. When page is rendered by the browser there is only HTML.

Comment: Ohh dang!!...I have to pass this variable to Controller's action method so that I can store it to MongoDB..How else can I do achieve this?

Comment: You should read about Ajax and how Javascript can communicate back to a server

Answer (score 0):

**in LARGE lines**

have your php get your value from a page wich serves this variable via js, then assign it to your php var

understand what i mean ?